# Python date formatting ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I was just iterating over a log and trying to find the difference in timestamps, between logs.
Below is my unit test code of the problem. Trying to understand why this is not being parsed in the format. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#import datetime
#import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

string1 = "02-23-24 13:37:46 0006847636: MKAP: Download"
string2 = "02-23-24 11:33:26 0000352403: MKAP: Download"
           #%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S %f
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(string2[:28].strip())
    if string2[30:] == "MKAP: Download":
        print("True")
        dt1 = datetime.strptime(string1[:28], "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S %f")
        dt2 = datetime.strptime(string2[:28], "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S %f")
        delta = dt2 - dt1
        print("Test", delta)

    else:
        print("False")
```

Error:

```
"C:\Scripts\python.exe" "ScriptFilter/test1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ScriptFilter/test1.py", line 8, in <module>
    dt1 = datetime.strptime(str_dt1, "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S %f")
  File "lib\_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "Python37\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 7636
```

Comment: Your format strings are year-month-day but your data appears to be month-day-year

Comment: Parsing directive `"%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S %f"` is correct, however Python's strptime can only parse up to 6 digits of fractional seconds with `%f` (you seem to have 10); its max. datetime resolution is microseconds. What is `0006847636` supposed to be? 684763.6 nanoseconds?

Comment: @FObersteiner it can be reproduced without last entity of %f
string1 = "02-23-24 13:37:46 0006847636: MVID: Download"
string2 = "02-23-24 11:33:26 0000352403: MVID: Download"
           #%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S %f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(string2[:28].strip())

    if string2[30:] == "MVID: Download":
         print("True")
         dt1 = datetime.strptime(string1[:18], "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S") 
         dt2 = datetime.strptime(string2[:18], "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S") 
         delta = dt2 - dt1
         print("Test", delta)
    else:
        print("False")

Comment: of course, but do you need the information stored in those 10 digits you were trying to parse with `%f`?

Answer (score 0):

The format of the date stuff is not correct. Try this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(string2[:28].strip())
    if string2[30:] == "MKAP: Download":
        print("True")
        dt1 = datetime.strptime(str(string1[:28]), "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S %f")  # Corrected format
        dt2 = datetime.strptime(string2[:28].strip(), "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S %f")  # Corrected format
        delta = dt2 - dt1
        print("Test", delta)
    else:
        print("False")
```

Comment: sorry my bad, i have posted earlier version. i have corrected now, this error still reproduces with this format corrected